# How to share a folder with SMB in KDE Plasma 5.4 and Dolphin 15.08.1

Tags: samba, kde5

I installed samba and kdenetwork-filesharing packets. When I do a right click on a folder I don't have a 'share' option in 'properties' submenu.

What is the easiest GUI way to share a folder via SMB protocol in Plasma 5?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Install the required packages:

```
sudo apt-get install kdenetwork-filesharing libsmbclient samba smbclient
```

After installing those packages, the sharing feature becomes available in Dolphin:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's because of this bug
https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=351699

We just have to wait and configure /etc/samba/smb.conf manualy.

Comment: FYI bug 351699 was fixed 2015-10, and in Dolphin 15.12.3 with KDE Frameworks 5.23.0 (probably Kubuntu 16.04) I see a Share tab.